# ASP.NET MVC Pass data from many <img> withe the same name to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

on my View, I have many <.img /> looking like that:

```
<img id="img1" name="myName" alt='aa' href='..' />
<img id="img2" name="myName" alt='bb' href='..' />
<img id="img3" name="myName" alt='cc' href='..' />
```

the question is, is it possible to get the `alt` attribute from the all <.img />'s with the same `name` and pass it to the controller as a e.g `string[]` ? The first thought was to use jQuery to join all that attributes as a one string and then pass it to the controller, but I'm wondering if there is some other approach

Comment: i guess it depends on how you want to process it at the controller end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jquery to get all the alt values and send them to the server as an AJAX request:

```
var alts = $('img[name=myName]').map(function(i, item) {
    return $(item).attr('alt');
});

$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    data: { myName: alts.toArray() },
    traditional: true,
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);            
    }
});
```

Comment: I pass the alts variable as a value to the hidden field, then I get its value on the server side (in the controller). The problem is, I get the "[object Object]" instead of the value I expect

Comment: @Tony, what hidden field? With the code snippet I provided you don't need any hidden field. You directly send the values as an AJAX request. If you want to use hidden fields, you will need multiple: one for each `alt`.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. You'll have to use client-side scripting to send those values to the server.

There's no other way to capture them on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways get send data back to the server: the query-string and form POST values.  If you want those alt tags sent back to the server you'll have to:

- use JavaScript to take the alt information off the images.
- for each image create a hidden input inside a form on the page.
- each hidden input needs the same name with a value for each image.
- submit the form via JavaScript.
- MVC's binding will put each hidden inputs with the same name into a string[] you can use in your controller.